# VSCODE Tricks: Replace the end of a line that has the beginning matching some string

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to do some hacky replacement here on a project.

I have some lines like this:

`console.log('My Cool Log');`

And I would like to do some replacing, so they become like this:

`logger.info({ message: 'My Cool Log' });`

The start of the string is easy, just do something like:

`/console.log(/logger.info({ message: /`

then we get:

`logger.info({ message: 'My Cool Log');`

My question is: is there a way to do the replacement at the end of the string ?

I basically need to replace the `');` by `} ');` where the line starts with `logger.info({ message:` .

Comment: You should state and tag what language you are using.  Is a find/replace in the files acceptable?  Is this in just the current file or across files?

Answer (score 0):

Find: `\bconsole\.log\((.*?)\);`
Replace: `logger.info({ message: $1 });`

See [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qu1wFH/1).

Comment: I was looking for a easy way to do on the Interface, but that did the trick, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "on the Interface"?  But you could put those values into the Find Widget (Ctrl+F).